# Qt Connections: Using Lambda Expression Resets Passed int Variable (Weird)

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

Consider the following code:

```
int counter = 0;

QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);

connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this, &counter]() mutable {
    counter++;
    qDebug() << counter;
});

timer->start(500);
```

Expected:

```
1
2
3
4
...
```

Output:

```
32766 (a random number)
...
```

Is there some undefined stuff going on here? I can't find anything about this effect.

Comment: You capture a reference to a local variable. Once that local variable dies (because you leave the scope it was defined in) you have a dangling reference.

Comment: That was the solution! After making "counter" into a class member variable, it never died, and no more dangling reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&counter` in the `[]` means you are capturing `counter` by-reference in the lambda.

If the variable `int counter` has gone out of scope (as local variables are wont to do), then this means you have a dangling reference; using it is undefined behavior.

The easy way to fix this is to just capture counter by value -- `[this, counter]` instead of `[this, &counter]`.  Then the lambda will own its own copy of the state of `counter`.  As it is mutable, it will have permission to edit its own state.